# Comparative Application ebs vs s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I am new to cloud environment. I do understand the definition and storage types EBS and S3. I wanted to understand the application of EBS as compared to S3.

I do understand EBS looks like a device for heavy though put operations. I cannot find any application where this can be used in comparison to S3. I could think of putting server logs on EBS on magnetic storage, as one EBS can be attached to one instance.

S3 you can use the scaling property to add some heavy data and expand in real time. We can deploy our slef managed dbs on this service.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Please help me understand what is best suited for what and application of them in comparison with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, they are primarily different types of storage:

- **Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)** is a persistent disk-storage service, which provides storage volumes to a virtual machine (similar to VMDK files in VMWare)
- **Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)** is an object store system that stores files as objects and optionally makes them available across the Internet.

So, how do people choose which to use? It's quite simple... If they need a volume mounted on an Amazon EC2 instance, they need to use Amazon EBS. It gives them a `C:`, `D:` drive, etc in Windows and a mountable volume in Linux. Computers traditionally expect to have locally-attached disk storage. Put simply: **If the operating system or an application running on an Amazon EC2 instance wants to store data locally, it will use EBS.**

**EBS Volumes** are actually stored on two physical devices in case of failure, but an EBS volume appears as a single volume. The volume size must be selected when the volume is created. The volume exists in a single Availability Zone and can only be attached to EC2 instances in the same Availability Zone. EBS Volumes *persist* even when the attached EC2 instance is Stopped; when the instance is Started again, the disk remains attached and all data has been presrved.

**Amazon S3**, however, is something quite different. It is a storage *service* that allows files to be uploaded/downloaded (`PutObject`, `GetObject`) and files are replicated across at least three data centers. Files can optionally be accessed via the Internet via HTTP/HTTPS without requiring a web server. There are no limits on the amount of data that can be stored. Access can be granted per-object, per-bucket via a Bucket Policy, or via IAM Users and Groups.

Amazon S3 is a good option when data needs to be shared (both locally and across the Internet), retained for long periods, backed-up (or even for storing backups) and made accessible to other systems. However, **applications need to specifically coded to use Amazon S3** and many traditional application expect to store data on a **local drive** rather than on a separate storage service.

While Amazon S3 has many benefits, there are still situations where **Amazon EBS is a better storage choice**:

- When using applications that expect to **store data locally**
- For storing **temporary files**
- When applications want to **partially update files**, because the smallest storage unit in S3 is a file and updating a part of a file requires re-uploading the whole file
- For **very High-IO situations**, such as databases (EBS Provisioned IOPS can provide volumes up to 20,000 IOPS)
- For creating **volume snapshots** as backups
- For creating **Amazon Machine Images (AMIs)** that can be used to boot EC2 instances

**Bottom line:** They are primarily different types of storage and each have their own usage sweet-spot, just like a Database is a good form of storage depending upon the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we can say we use EBS for mounting and S3 for remote access via service (using URL - internal or external). But still we can deploy our owned db on s3 instance, right ? but will be able to access this via db access url , right ?

Comment: Databases cannot use S3 for storage. Databases like to store data on a filesystem and S3 is not a filesystem. There are tools available (eg Expandrive, Cloudberry Drive) that can mount S3 as a filesystem, but these would not be fast enough to support database updates. There is no such thing as an "S3 instance".

Comment: I found the uses case for the same https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/#availabilityanddurability Alos please correct my assumtions after reading the docs, one EBS can be attached to one EC2 instance at a time, atlhouh it is visble across AZ, one EBS cannot be attached with multiple EC2 instace at a time?

Comment: So if I want to use my own MySQL server which is managed by me where can I place it and multiple EC2 instances must point to the same. I am assuming, for this I will deploy mysql server on ec2 connected to EBS, where the db files will lie on EBS volumes , mysql application will run on ec2 instance. and my application layer ec2 instance will communicate with this the db's ec2 instance , right ?

Comment: That is correct. Amazon S3 would not be involved. Alternatively, you could use Amazon RDS, which is a fully-managed database that would be deployed on a separate server.